# UML class diagram vs java codings

Tags: java, uml

I have following UML class diagram and java coding for each, please tell me is my coding are correct or incorrect according to the diagram,

[image]

[Diagram 1]

```
Class A{
  B b = new B();
}

Class B{
  A a = new A();
}
```

---

[Diagram 2]

```
Class B{
  private void methodA(){
      A a = new A();
  }
}
```

Comment: If I need to create and initialize an instance of class A inside a method in Class B, how does that is shown in a UML diagramme?

Comment: it cannot be done with a class diagram, because such a diagram shows just the entities with their properties and operations as well as relationships between two of them.

Comment: thanx for the reply  christian.vogel, so, if there is such a relationship does it shows as ----> OR ___> when "initialize an instance of class A inside a method in Class B"?

Comment: no there is nothing like that in class diagrams. on this page you will find mostly all what you can map with class diagrams: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/sep04/bell/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code1

```
Class A{
  B b;
}

Class B{
  A a;
}
```

Code2

```
Class A{

          public void methodA(){

      }
    }

    Class B{
    A a;
      public void methodB(){

      }
```

}

Comment: the second code is not correct because a UML diagram cannot show what kind of body content has a method. So you cannot declare a local variable `B b` in `methodA`. Furthermore there is no association, aggregation or composition from `A` to `B` so there shouldnt be a variable of type `B` in `A`.

Comment: An association does not mean aggregation,  it only means that the sorce class accesses the target class

Answer (score 1):

Diagram1 looks fine. Diagram2 is incorrect.

1. methodA/B schould be public
2. You should have an attribute in class B, rather than in init classes in the body of the method, which represents the association to class A
3. You should'nt have to initialize the classes in the methods according to just map the UML diagram to classes.

[Diagram 2]

```
class A {
  public void methodA() {}
}

class B {
  A a;

  public void methodB() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes in your Java implementation of the diagrams:

- `+` specifies `public` visibility, while your methods are `private`
- The diagram does not specify what's in the body of each method; both bodies need to be empty
- The diagram does not specify how the variables `a` and `b` are initialized, so `= new A()` and `= new B()` need to be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an association between two classifiers then you also create attributes in the UML2 class diagram. Method flows is displayed in the sequence diagram.

If you are not sure of your code the easiest is to download the 30 days evaluation of EclipseUML Omondo : http://www.uml2.org/eclipse-java-galileo-SR2-win32_eclipseUML2.2_package_may2010.zip

Just unzip and it works.